# How to create a scrolling button

Tags: javascript, html, scrollview, dom-events

I have code where the primary function is when a tab is clicked. The tab will highlight and move to that section of the code. The Character tab works and the About tab just takes me to the top of the page so I don't know for sure if that's working. However the Contact Us tab and the Battle Drives tab is complete wrong. The contact us tab takes me to the battle drive tab and the Battle Drive tab takes me below it. I want to create a function where when a tab is pressed it takes exactly to that specific element/section. Would it make more sense to add the id's to a specific element where it's being used instead of just adding to a div element.

```js
const makeNavLinksSmooth = () => {
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tab'); // add the name of the class you want to highlight when section appears

  // this for loop checks all the elemnts which have class '.nav-tab' and adds a click event to it so it can scroll to that section
  for (let n in navLinks) {
    if (navLinks.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
      navLinks[n].addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector(navLinks[n].hash)
          .scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth"
          });
      });
    }
  }
}

const spyScrolling = () => {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.panel'); // a common name give to each section to identify them

  // on scroll will highligh the nav item when reaches to the specific section
  window.onscroll = () => {
    const scrollPos = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

    for (let s in sections) {
      console.log(scrollPos, sections[s].offsetTop)
      if (sections.hasOwnProperty(s) && sections[s].offsetTop <= scrollPos + 100) {
        const id = sections[s].id;
        document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
        document.querySelector(`a[href*=${ id }]`).parentNode.classList.add('active');
      }
    }
  }
}

makeNavLinksSmooth();
spyScrolling();
```

```html
<body class="scroll-area" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0">
  <header class="section">

    <!-- container -->
    <div class="">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="images/ShoeJackCityLogo.png" class="img logo">
      </div>
      <nav id="site-nav">
        <ul class="group">
          <li><a href="https://twitter.com/_ShoeJackCity">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-tab" href="#characters">Characters</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-tab" href="#battle_drives">Battle Drives</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a class="nav-tab" href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-tab" href="#follow_us">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </div>

  </header>

  <div class="content-area group section">
    <!-- container -->
    <div class="container panel" id="about">
      <!-- row -->
      <div class="Title">
        <h1>ShoeJackCity</h1>
        <p>SJC is a mobile game where you can buy, sell, and play in a compettive 11v1 fighting tournament against real users to win sneakers.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
          <div class="game-play">
            <video controls>
                        <source src="videos/RPReplay_Final1595357560.MP4" type="video/MP4">
                    </video>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
          <h3>About</h3>
          <p>Shoe Jack City is a first of its kind mobile gaming resell app that allows players to buy,sell, and compete for rare, high-end sneakers in a tournament style battle royale.</p>

          <p>Inspired by the MegaMan Battle Network Series, players can choose thier Anomalies, collect battle drives to unleash powerful attacks and hidden abilities.</p>

          <p>Buy and/or sell sneakers, and Dominate your way against friends and compete in 1v1 tournament battle royale to win top tier sneakers and reduce your sellers transaction fee!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- container -->
    <div class="container panel" id="follow_us">
      <!-- row -->
      <h1 class="m-2">Follow us/Contact Us</h1>
      <!-- row -->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- col -->
        <div class="col col-sm-8">
          <div class="col col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
            <!-- box-a -->
            <div class="box-twitter">
              <p><a href="https://twitter.com/_ShoeJackCity">Twitter</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /box-a -->
          </div>
          <!-- /col -->

          <!-- col -->
          <div class="col col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
            <!-- box-a -->
            <div class="box-insta">
              <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com/_shoejackcity/?hl=en">Instagram</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /box-a -->
          </div>
          <!-- /col -->

          <!-- col -->
          <div class="col col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
            <!-- box-a -->
            <div class="box-facebook">
              <p>Facebook</p>
            </div>
            <!-- /box-a -->
          </div>
          <!-- /col -->
        </div>
        <!-- col -->
        <div class="col col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
          <!-- box-a -->
          <form>
            <div class="box-b">
              <input id="email" class="email-input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="subscribe-button">
          </form>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container panel" id="battle_drives">
      <!-- row -->
      <div class="row">

        <!-- col -->
        <h2>Battle Drives</h2>
        <div class=" push-down-sm">


          <!-- row -->
          <div class="row">

            <!-- col -->
            <div class="col col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
              <!-- box-a -->
              <div class="box-a">
                <img src="images/BC_Area_advance.png">
                <p>Slices 1 enemy directly Slices 1 enemy directly Slices 1 enemy directly ahead. Range is 2 spaces, 80dmg, 40MB, LVL 1</p>
              </div>
              <!-- /box-a -->
            </div>
            <!-- /col -->

            <!-- col -->
            <div class="col col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
              <!-- box-a -->
              <div class="box-a">
                <img src="images/BC_Area_advance.png">
                <p>AreaAdvance: Steals up to the first 4 available spaces. MB: 200, LV 1</p>
              </div>
              <!-- /box-a -->
            </div>
            <!-- /col -->

            <!-- col -->
            <div class="col col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
              <!-- box-a -->
              <div class="box-a">
                <img src="images/BC_Area_advance.png">
                <p>Mamba Mentality - raise attack power of Level 1 chip x2. MB:50, LV 1</p>
              </div>
              <!-- /box-a -->
            </div>
            <!-- /col -->

            <!-- col -->
            <div class="col col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
              <!-- box-a -->
              <div class="box-a">
                <img src="images/BC_Area_advance.png">
                <p>Mamba Mentality - raise attack power of Level 1 chip x2. MB:50, LV 1</p>
              </div>
              <!-- /box-a -->
            </div>
            <!-- /col -->

          </div>
          <!-- /row -->

          <!-- row -->


        </div>
        <!-- /col -->



      </div>
      <!-- /row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
    <!-- container -->
  </div>
  <div class="container  p-2 panel" id="characters">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 class="">Characters</h2>

      <!-- col -->
      <div class="col col-xs-6">
        <img class="postion" src="images/Marbelle_ingame_concept.png">
      </div>
      <!-- /col -->

      <!-- col -->
      <div class="col col-xs-6">
        <img class="postion" src="images/Ade_ingame_concept.png">
      </div>
      <!-- /col -->

    </div>
    <!-- /row -->
  </div>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2014 - This is the footer.</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

[image: pokeymon]

[image: pokeymon-gone]

Comment: I prefer ids because then there would be no need to go through for loops every time you click. It would be cleaner and demand less processing. That's what I think, I could be wrong :)

Comment: Create a snippet if possible

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  height: 3000px;
  background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Change Background Gradient on Scroll</h1>

<h2>Linear Gradient - Top to Bottom</h2>
<p>This linear gradient starts at the top. It starts green, transitioning to blue.</p>

<h2 style="position:fixed;">Scroll to see the effect.</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

for more information follow this link
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_bg_gradient_scroll.asp